# How to fix the display list on the department in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
{
                roomDept.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="flex flex-col pb-2 items-center">
                    <div className="flex pb-2 w-full">
                      <SelectPicker
                        placeholder="Select Room"
                        data={room['data']}
                        labelKey="name"
                        valueKey="code"
                        className="w-1/2"
                        cleanable={false}
                        disabledItemValues={roomDept.map(x => x.code)}
                        onChange={(value) => {
                          control.setValue('rooms', _setRoomDept(value, index, 'code'));
                          const _ID = room['data'].filter(room => room.code === value).map(x => x.id);
                          (async function fetch() {
                            let _department = await getAllDepartment({ room: _ID[0] });
                            department[`department-${index}`] = _department['data']['data'];
                            setDepartment(department)
                          })()
                        }}
                        value={item.code}
                      />

                      <span className="px-1 leading-8 text-2xl">-</span>

                      <SelectPicker
                        placeholder="Select Department"
                        data={department[`department-${index}`]}
                        labelKey="name"
                        valueKey="code"
                        className="w-1/2"
                        cleanable={false}
                        onChange={(value) => { control.setValue('rooms', _setRoomDept(value, index, 'dept')) }}
                        value={item.dept}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
```

I have a problem when I try to select an item on the room on the department doesn't display the data on it. for example I select `Room1` then on the department it should display automatically after selecting a Room but on my side for example I select the `Room1` which it has a department it doesn't display the list on the department then when I try to select another room like `Room2` it will display the data list on the department which it display at the first place which I select the room2

Comment: Hi, it is a bit difficult to understand what the problem is. If you can throw more lights. When you select `Room2`, does it display departments for `Room1`?

Comment: it doesn't display the departments for ```Room1``` it will display after I select another room

Comment: for example I have a department on the ```Room1``` then on the ```Room2``` I dont have departments. then when I try to select a room like ```Room1``` it will not display the list on the department. but when I try to select the ```Room2``` it will display the list of ```Room1``` department.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with;

```
department[`department-${index}`]
```

What I would try:

1. I won't have dept and room in one map function
2. Since you are setting `setDepartment(department)`. I will check and do a map for the department state which will load the departments tied to a room since changing a room fetches its department and sets it to a state.

Comment: How do I tied to the room?

Comment: From what I am seeing;

1. Rooms already exist here `room['data']`

2. OnChange, you are getting the room ID and setting it to _ID here `const _ID = room['data'].filter(room => room.code === value).map(x => x.id);`

3.  You are fetching departments in a room here `let _department = await getAllDepartment({ room: _ID[0] });`

NOW: Set this _department to a state and use it in the data attribute for the department SelectPicker component.